# Out of bounds excpetion on subarray

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, cell

A little lost on correct logic to make a subarray using for loops and not using the arrays class.

```
Cell[][] subArray = new Cell[10][78];
Cell[][] padded = makePaddedArray(message);
for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = animationPattern; j < subArray[i].length + animationPattern; j++) {
        subArray[i][j - animationPattern] = padded[i][j]; // out of bounds exception here -- column length?
    }
}
```

Where `animationPattern` is an `Integer` equal to 1 for the most part and the padded array has the the dimensions [10][ ]. Also a cell is just an object.

I just honestly am looking for some clarification on how to make a subarray work here and the basis behind the out of bounds exception I'm receiving.

EDIT: makePaddedArray returns a 2D cell array with dimensions [10][x], where x is greater than or equal to 165.

Comment: For your own benefit, use either a debugger or some print statements to see what the value of i and j is at each iteration. Then you can compare the length of the arrays to those values and see where the bounds are exceeded.

Also, the bounds exception that you receive, is it a negative number or a positive number? In other words are you going under or over the length of the array?

Comment: Let's assume makePaddedArray return Cell[x][y], It's your x<=10?

Comment: @RogerDwan I made an edit, but yes the x is always 10

Comment: make sure is `makePaddedArray(message)` return same values as `Cell[10][78];` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length; i++) {
```

for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < subArray.length-1; i++) {
```

As you start from 0, and not from 1, you need to lower the end of the array also by 1.